# SSRS How can I change the background color of the first row on each new page

Tags: reporting-services

I want to change the background color of every first row on my new page in SSRS report. After the page break I want to give a new color for the back ground of the firat row only.

Thank You.

Blessed.

Comment: Are all rows contained within the same `tablix/matrix`?

Comment: Yes I have one tablix and I made an expression group of 24 pages each page like this =System.Math.Ceiling((RowNumber(Nothing))/ 24).

Comment: The challenge is from here: I wanted to hide the duplicates and I managed by displaying the row only if I have different row from previous value like this =IIf(Fields!TitreCours.Value = Previous(Fields!TitreCours.Value), "Silver","Teal") in background color of each columns of my tablix.

Comment: But when I have many records with the same columns values there should be some pages that are invisible as the background color is sliver. So in order to overcome this shortcoming, I wanted to give a specific background at each first row per page.

Comment: I would worry about filtering the duplicate values out in your query initially. Because you know that you have 24 rows per page, you could set the row background color expression to something like `=IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 24 = 0, "Silver", "Teal")`.  The only way that I can think of to accomplish what you want is with the rownumber operator which does not take into account whether or not a row is **visible** to the user; which is why you would need to filter duplicates ahead of time.

Comment: It is not the whole row that is duplicated just few columns cz I have dates and names that are differents each row but courses may be the same for differents dates so I have to keep dates visible all over my tablix and hide courses titles when repeated

Comment: An alternative background color expression could be `=IIf(RowNumber("<24rowGroupName>") = 0, "Silver", "Teal")`.  Using the group name in the row number expression will allow you to determine if the current row is the first row of the group or not.

Comment: I am using this RowNumber("Group1")=1 and is working but the last page has less than 24 rows and it is not working at that specific page. Any idea?

Comment: I'm really not sure why it wouldn't work on the last page. The fact that there aren't 24 rows on the last page shouldn't matter.  Maybe try adding `RowNumber("Group1")` to one of your textbox expressions so that you can see what row number is being calculated.

Comment: Suprisingly the value  of RowNumber("Group1") for one column on the last page begins with 3 but other columns are starting with 1.. I am looking why the system is behaving like this for just one column cz on the previous page, the value of the first row is 1 and the last row is 24 for the entire row. This misbehavior is only with a set of data (depending on values I pass as parameters)